# Azure OpenAi disable public internet access

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-openai

In Open AI networking section I have set the "allow access from" to disabled. Due to this configuration I have created private endpoint so I cannot connect to my Open AI via virtual network. However, I can now connect from public internet and from virtual network. How can I disable public internet completely?

Comment: Do you want to restrict Chat Service in Open AI or restrict Open AI from Public network?

Comment: I would like to restrict everything

Comment: If you create a Private Endpoint with Vnet, it will restrict only Chat Service, if you want to block Azure AI Studio also create NSG rule based on your requirement.

Comment: my NSG is set to pretty much "deny-all" for inbound traffic but that does not seem to affect how the Azure AI Studio works. To me it looks as if Azure AI Studio is not integrated into virtual network at all based on how the communication with storage account does not work if the communication is forced to vnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can now connect from public internet and from virtual network. How can I disable public internet completely?

If you create an `OpenAI` with a `Private Endpoint`, it only blocks the `Chat Service` inside `OpenAI Studio`. However, you can't block `OpenAI Studio` itself, as it's a cloud-based service that must be accessed through the public internet.

**Portal View:**

[image]

**VIrtual Network Configuration**

[image]

To secure your `Cognitive Services` resource, you should first disable all access to traffic from all networks by default. Then, you should configure rules that grant access to traffic from specific `VNets`.

Refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-virtual-networks?context=/azure/cognitive-services/openai/context/context&tabs=portal#scenarios) for more details about Cognitive Services resources.