# Integrating an Azure web app and Azure OpenAI with a virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway, azure-openai

I'm trying to secure my Azure OpenAI web app as much as possible, but I can't figure out how to keep traffic behind the application gateway inside my virtual network.

Here's what I have so far:

- Application gateway with a public IP (right now it's listening on port 80, there's no SSL) inside its own subnet.
- Web app (created via app services) behind the application gateway with the default *.azurewebsites.net domain. Using access restrictions, I only allowed access to this app from the gateway's public IP. This web app calls my Azure OpenAI deployment via the Python SDK.
- Azure OpenAI deployment allowing access from all networks. There's a private endpoint for Azure OpenAI, but it has no effect since under *Networking > Firewalls and virtual networks* I choose *All networks*.
- Right now, I'm not using any authentication mechanism for the users like Active Directory.

Diagram:

[image]

I would now like to limit network traffic like this:

- Put the web app in the same virtual network used by Azure OpenAI's private endpoint
- Allow traffic to Azure OpenAI only from the web app's subnet
- Limit Azure OpenAI traffic by using the private endpoint
- Maybe use a private endpoint for the web app

I started by enabling VNet integration for the web app and putting it in its own subnet. The subnet is in same virtual network as Azure OpenAI and has a service endpoint for `Microsoft.CognitiveServices`.

The app can no longer call Azure OpenAI (I get a 500 error). I tried whitelisting the app's subnet in the Azure OpenAI networking settings ("Allow access from Selected Networks and Private Endpoints") but that didn't help.

How should I change my setup so as little traffic as possible leaves my virtual network?

Answer (score 0):

> Integrating an Azure web app and Azure OpenAI with a virtual network.

To integrate `Azure Web App` and `Azure OpenAI` with a virtual network, follow the below steps

1. Disable all networks and enable **Private Endpoint** with your virtual network and subnet in `Open AI`

[image]

2. Once the `Open AI Studio` is created, it will be accessible only from the same virtual network. If you try to access it from another network, you will get the below error

[image]

3.Create a `Web app` with a `Private endpoint` using the same virtual network and subnet..

[image]

4. Once I create the web app, I will deploy the `Open AI` to the same web app.

[image]

5.If you try to access the `Open AI` from outside the network, you will get the below error.

[image]

6.The same is working if you try to access the `Open AI` from the same virtual network subnet address

To test the connection, I created a virtual machine within the same `VNet` and tested the `Chat Service`. It is working as expected.

[image]

Reference: [DNS configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#dns-configuration) & [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565550/azure-openai-disable-public-internet-access/76572982#76572982)